# Unexpected behaviour in famo.us javascript

Tags: javascript, famo.us

The code below creates up the elements for a grid, and arranges it using the transformOut method. This part works fine, but I then want the grid to collapse in to the centre on mousedown, and spring back out again on mouseup. However, all subsequent calls to either the transformIn or transformOut function result in the items going in and out. A working example is here:
http://codepen.io/timsig/pen/JdXYwE
Code as follows, thanks for any help.

```
define('main', function (require, exports, module) {
    var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');

    var View            = require('famous/core/View');
    var Surface         = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Modifier        = require('famous/core/Modifier');
    var StateModifier   = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
    var EventHandler    = require('famous/core/EventHandler');
    var PhysicsEngine   = require('famous/physics/PhysicsEngine');
    var Transitionable  = require('famous/transitions/Transitionable');
    var SpringTransition= require('famous/transitions/SpringTransition');
    var Particle        = require('famous/physics/bodies/Particle');
    var Drag            = require('famous/physics/forces/Drag');
    var RepulsionForce  = require('famous/physics/forces/Repulsion');
    var Wall            = require('famous/physics/constraints/Wall');
    var Random          = require('famous/math/Random');
    var Transform       = require('famous/core/Transform');

    Transitionable.registerMethod('spring', SpringTransition);



    var context = Engine.createContext();

    var cols = 5;
    var rows = 5;
    var gridSize = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) / 1.5;
    var itemSize = gridSize / (cols + 1);
    var gridItems = [];
    var transformOutArray = [itemSize / 2 - gridSize / 2,
                            (itemSize / 2 - gridSize / 2) / 2,
                            0,
                            (gridSize / 2 - itemSize / 2) / 2,
                            gridSize / 2 - itemSize / 2];

    var transformInArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(transformOutArray);
    transformInArray.reverse();


    var cameraView = new View();
    var camera = new Modifier({
        origin: [0.5, 0.5],
        align: [0.5, 0.5]
    });

    context.add(camera).add(cameraView);




    function createGridItems(){
        for (var r = 0; r < rows; r += 1){
            for (var c = 0; c < cols; c += 1){
               var gridItem = new Surface({
                    size: [itemSize, itemSize],
                    properties:{
                        backgroundColor: '#aa62bb'
                    },
                    content: r + "," + c
                });

                gridItem.mod = new StateModifier({
                    origin: [0.5, 0.5],
                    align: [0.5, 0.5],
                    transform: Transform.identity
                });

                gridItem.idx = gridItems.length;

                gridItem.transformOutrs = transformOutArray[r];
                gridItem.transformOutcs = transformOutArray[c];
                gridItem.transformInrs = transformInArray[r];
                gridItem.transformIncs = transformInArray[c];

                gridItems.push(gridItem);
                cameraView.add(gridItem.mod).add(gridItem);
            }
        }
    }


    function transformOut(){
      console.log('transform out')
        for (var i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i+=1){
            var index = i;
            var gridItem = gridItems[index];

            var tran = Transform.translate(gridItem.transformOutrs, gridItem.transformOutcs);
            gridItem.mod.setTransform(tran, {
                method: 'spring',
                dampingRatio: 0.5,
                period: 600
            });
        }

    }

    function transformIn(){
        console.log('transform in');
        for (var j = 0; j < gridItems.length; j+=1){
            var index = j;
            var gridItem = gridItems[index];

            var tran = Transform.translate(gridItem.transformInrs, gridItem.transformIncs);
            gridItem.mod.setTransform(tran, {
                method: 'spring',
                dampingRatio: 0.5,
                period: 600
            });
        }


    }

    createGridItems();
    console.log (transformOutArray);
    console.log (transformInArray);
    transformOut();

    Engine.on('mousedown', transformIn);
    Engine.on('mouseup', transformOut);

});
```

Comment: Note that `setTranform` is now deprecated on `Modifier`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `Transform` back to the identity will return items back to their default on transform. Currently they are transitioning back to original once the new transform is set, then apply the new transform. You are only reversing their order with the new transforms.

```js
    function transformIn(){
        console.log('transform in');
        for (var j = 0; j < gridItems.length; j+=1){
            var index = j;
            var gridItem = gridItems[index];

            gridItem.mod.setTransform(Transform.identity, {
                method: 'spring',
                dampingRatio: 0.5,
                period: 600
            });
        }
    }
```

#### Example snippet:

```js
define('main', function (require, exports, module) {
 var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');

 var View            = require('famous/core/View');
    var Surface         = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Modifier        = require('famous/core/Modifier');
    var StateModifier   = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
    var EventHandler    = require('famous/core/EventHandler');
    var PhysicsEngine   = require('famous/physics/PhysicsEngine');
    var Transitionable  = require('famous/transitions/Transitionable');
    var SpringTransition= require('famous/transitions/SpringTransition');
    var Particle        = require('famous/physics/bodies/Particle');
    var Drag            = require('famous/physics/forces/Drag');
    var RepulsionForce  = require('famous/physics/forces/Repulsion');
    var Wall            = require('famous/physics/constraints/Wall');
    var Random          = require('famous/math/Random');
    var Transform       = require('famous/core/Transform');

    Transitionable.registerMethod('spring', SpringTransition);

    var context = Engine.createContext();

    var cols = 5;
    var rows = 5;
    var gridSize = Math.min(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight) / 1.5;
    var itemSize = gridSize / (cols + 1);
    var gridItems = [];
    var transformOutArray = [itemSize / 2 - gridSize / 2,
                            (itemSize / 2 - gridSize / 2) / 2,
                            0,
                            (gridSize / 2 - itemSize / 2) / 2,
                            gridSize / 2 - itemSize / 2];

    var transformInArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(transformOutArray);
    transformInArray.reverse();


    var cameraView = new View();
    var camera = new Modifier({
        origin: [0.5, 0.5],
        align: [0.5, 0.5]
    });

    context.add(camera).add(cameraView);

    function createGridItems(){
        for (var r = 0; r < rows; r += 1){
            for (var c = 0; c < cols; c += 1){
               var gridItem = new Surface({
                    size: [itemSize, itemSize],
                    properties:{
                        backgroundColor: '#aa62bb'
                    },
                    content: r + "," + c
                });

                gridItem.mod = new StateModifier({
                    origin: [0.5, 0.5],
                    align: [0.5, 0.5],
                    transform: Transform.identity
                });

                gridItem.idx = gridItems.length;

                gridItem.transformOutrs = transformOutArray[r];
                gridItem.transformOutcs = transformOutArray[c];
                gridItem.transformInrs = transformInArray[r];
                gridItem.transformIncs = transformInArray[c];

                gridItems.push(gridItem);
                cameraView.add(gridItem.mod).add(gridItem);
            }
        }
    }

    function transformOut(){
      console.log('transform out');
        for (var i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i+=1){
            var index = i;
            var gridItem = gridItems[index];
        
            var tran = Transform.translate(gridItem.transformOutrs, gridItem.transformOutcs);
            gridItem.mod.setTransform(tran, {
                method: 'spring',
                dampingRatio: 0.5,
                period: 600
            });
        }

    }

    function transformIn(){
        console.log('transform in');
        for (var j = 0; j < gridItems.length; j+=1){
            var index = j;
            var gridItem = gridItems[index];
        
            gridItem.mod.setTransform(Transform.identity, {
                method: 'spring',
                dampingRatio: 0.5,
                period: 600
            });
        }
    }

    createGridItems();
   console.log (transformOutArray);
   console.log (transformInArray);
    transformOut();
    
    Engine.on('mousedown', transformIn);
   Engine.on('mouseup', transformOut);
    
});
require(['main']);
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />
<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE:** setTransform is now deprecated in Famo.us

> Deprecated: Prefer transformFrom with static Transform, or use a TransitionableTransform.

Comment: Many thanks again for your input. I was thinking that a transitionable transform would make more sense; as I am transitioning several items at the same time would this be more performant? Also,am I correct to infer that each modifer's transform stores an identity object (effectively the way back to where it came from). So if you wanted to reverse an animation that was created by chaining modifiers, you would have to set each one of their transform propeties back to identity?

Comment: [Transform.identity](https://github.com/Famous/famous/blob/master/src/core/Transform.js#L37) is a static matrix value. When a modifier's transform is set to this matrix value the return should be back to the origin. It is not really a reverse as much as a reset.